# How can I reverse a single String in Java 8 using Lambda and Streams?

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-stream

I have one string say `"Aniruddh"` and I want to reverse it using lambdas and streams in Java 8. How can I do it?

Comment: a) What have you tried so far? b) Are you trying to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Why do you insist on lambdas and streams?

Comment: Hello and welcome! It might be worth having a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which has some tips on how to ask a great question that'll get you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Why to invent **Wheel** again? Cannot use library function??

Answer (score 46):

Given a string like

```
String str = "Aniruddh";
```

the idiomatic solution is

```
String reversed = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
```

If, perhaps for educational purposes, you want to solve this by streaming over the string’s characters, you can do it like

```
String reversed = str.chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> (char)c)
    .reduce("", (s,c) -> c+s, (s1,s2) -> s2+s1);
```

This is not only much more complicated, it also has performance drawbacks.

The following solution eliminates boxing related overhead

```
String reversed = str.chars()
    .collect(StringBuilder::new,
             (b, c) -> b.insert(0, (char)c), (b1, b2) -> b1.insert(0, b2))
    .toString();
```

but is still less efficient because inserting into the beginning of an array based buffer implies copying all previously collected data.

The bottom line is, for real applications, stay with the idiomatic solution shown at the beginning.

Comment: ingenious way via `reduce` :)

Comment: I believe you mean "idiomatic", as opposed to "canonical".  I don't believe abstraction can be deemed canonical.

Comment: @Reilas yes, today, I’d rather use the word “idiomatic” here.

Comment: @Holger, lol! Despite that, great answer, +1.

Answer (score 9):

Try this for reverse a string using lambda and streams

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    public class Test  {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println(reverse("Anirudh"));;
        }
        public static String reverse(String string) {
            return Stream.of(string)
                .map(word->new StringBuilder(word).reverse())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        }
    }
```

Comment: kind of a testament to @satya's point... do we really need to use streams or lamdas in this case when `new StringBuilder(word).reverse()` provides the desired effect? IMHO, this is over engineered

Answer (score 4):

If you *really* want to do it for learning purposes, why not reverse the char array?

```
public static String reverse(String test) {
    return IntStream.range(0, test.length())
            .map(i -> test.charAt(test.length() - i - 1))
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, c) -> sb.append((char) c), StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to reversing your String. You can use an IntStream to pull the correct character out of a `char` array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] charArray = "Aniruddh".toCharArray();
    IntStream.range(0, charArray.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> charArray[(charArray.length - 1) - i])
        .forEach(System.out::print);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function<String, String> reverse = s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
```

Comment: Even if this is a valid answer, you'd better comment on what is going on and explain a bit of your code.

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, doesn't seem super efficient but will explain why:

```
String s = "blast";
IntStream.range(0, s.length()).           // create index [0 .. s.length - 1] 
   boxed().                               // the next step requires them boxed
   sorted(Collections.reverseOrder()).    // indices in reverse order
   map(i -> String.valueOf(s.charAt(i))). // grab each index's character 
   collect(Collectors.joining());         // join each single-character String into the final String
```

It would be better if there was a way to append all the Characters without converting each to `String` and then joining them. That's why I said it doesn't seem super efficient.

Comment: Sorting is redundant, you can generate a descending sequence of indices instead `IntStream.iterate(s.length() - 1, i -> i >= 0, i -> --i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative way would be to split the string into an array of string and use reduce() on it.

```
Stream.of("Aniruddh".split("")).reduce("", (reversed, character) -> character + reversed);
```

Comment: This is the best answer if you don't intend to use String Builder

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Noorus Khan";
       int len = str.length();
        IntStream.range(0, len)
                .map(i -> len - 1 - i)
                .mapToObj(j->str.charAt(j))
                .forEach(System.out::print);
```

output :: nahK surooN

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below technique to reverse a string using stream.

```
String str = "Aniruddh";

Stream.iterate(str.length()-1, n-> n >= 0, n-> n-1)
        .map(input::charAt)
        .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you're asking using streams is probably this:

```
String result = Stream.of("Aniruddh").map(__ -> "hddurinA").findFirst().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a String of length S, reverse the whole string without reversing the individual words in it. Words are separated by dots.

```
String str="abcd.efg.qwerty";

String reversed = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\.")).stream().map(m -> new 
StringBuilder(m).reverse().toString()).collect(Collectors.joining("."));

System.out.println(reversed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is another approach to reverse the input String `str` using Java 8 streams API.

```
String abc = Arrays.asList(str).stream()
    .map(s -> new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString())
    .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

A **custom collector** can be handy if you want to achieve it with **Stream API** (*I'm treating this task exclusively as an exercise*).

Since none of the contributors of this question mentioned this possibility, here's a brief description of how to do that.

#### Creating a Custom Collector

You can create a *custom collector* either inline by using one of the versions of the static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)) or by creating a `class` that implements the `Collector` interface.

[image]

- **Supplier** `Supplier<A>` is meant to provide a *mutable container* which store elements of the stream. It could be a `Collection`, `StringBuilder` or any other mutable object.
- **Accumulator** BiConsumer<A,T> defines how to add elements into the *container* provided by the *supplier*.
- **Combiner** `BinaryOperator<A> combiner()` establishes a rule on how to merge two *containers* in case of parallel execution.
- **Finisher** `Function<A,R>` is meant to produce the final result by transforming the mutable container.
- **Characteristics** allows to provide additional information, for instance `Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED` signifies that the collector does not guarantee to preserve initial order of elements when the source of the stream is ordered, which can provide better performance in parallel.

The minimum set of parameters boils down to **supplier**, **accumulator** and **combiner** which resembles the arguments of [`collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) operation with one difference - combiner argument expected by `of()` (*as well as the return type of the* `combiner()` *method*) is `BinaryOperator<A>`.

#### Implementations

The idea behind the first collector is to use `ArrayDeque` as a *mutable container* and add each element from the stream of *code points* to the front of the *deque*.

Portions of tasks created in parallel will result into several *deques* has to be combined in reversed order. Therefore, in the *combiner* the *left deque* (*containing values from closer to the start of the source string*) gets appended to the *right deque* (*containing values from closer to the end of the source string*), and the *right deque* is being returned as a result.

Finisher produces an array `int[]` of code point and returns a string based on it.

`Collector<Integer, Deque<Integer>, String>`

```
String source = "abcdefgh";

String reversed = source.codePoints()
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collector.of(
        ArrayDeque::new,
        Deque::addFirst,
        (Deque<Integer> left, Deque<Integer> right) -> { right.addAll(left); return right; },
        (Deque<Integer> deque) -> new String(
            deque.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray(),
            0,
            deque.size())
    ));
```

The second collector utilizes `char[]` as its mutable container which is being populated according to the indices of the source `IntStream`.

Combiner merges two arrays by peek the largest value for each position of the array.

Finisher utilizes constructor `new String(char[])` to generate the resulting string.

`Collector<Integer, char[], String>`

```
String reversed = IntStream.range(0, source.length())
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collector.of(
        () -> new char[source.length()],
        (char[] arr, Integer i) -> arr[(source.length() - 1) - i] = source.charAt(i),
        (char[] left, char[] right) -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < left.length; i++) left[i] = (char) Math.max(left[i], right[i]); return left;
        },
        String::new
    ));
```

**Output** (*for string* `"abcdefgh"`)

```
hgfedcba
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static String reverseStreams(String ex)
  {
    char[] charray=ex.toCharArray();
    StringWriter str=new StringWriter();
      IntStream.range(0, charray.length)
        .mapToObj(i->(charray[(charray.length-1)-i]))
     //   .collect(Collectors.toList())
        
        .forEach(s->str.append(s));
        return str.toString();
        
    
    

   }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "I am Vishwa Ratna";
    String[] split = str.split("");
    int len = str.length();
    String collect = IntStream.range(0, len).mapToObj(s -> {
        int k = len - 1;
        String sq = "";
        sq = split[k - s];
        --k;
        return sq;

    }).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

First you convert your `String` to `String array` then you iterate through it in reverse order using `Intstream` and then you `collect` your stream to string by `joining`.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach could be writing a custom comparator (this could help reverse any element in collection/array) which would always return "-1"."-1" being whenever 2 objects are compared the second object will be prior to first in placing order.

```
    Comparator<String> comparator = (s1,s2) -> -1;
    
    String reversed = Arrays.stream(input.split(""))
                           .sorted(comparator)
                           .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple Approach I used is

```
String str = "INDIA";
    IntStream.range(0, str.length()).forEach(i -> System.out.print(str.charAt(str.length() - 1 - i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "abc";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
Stream.of(str.split("")).forEach(c -> result.insert(0,c));
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.