# How to convert a stream of Character into array of Character using stream functions in java

Tags: java, java-stream

```
static public void reverseString(char[] s){
    Object[] upperCaseArray = IntStream.range(0,s.length)
            .mapToObj(index -> s[index])
            .map(Character::toUpperCase)
            .toArray();
}
```

Here `upperCaseArray` is of Object type how to convert it into `char[]` with stream functions?

Comment: Maybe you’re asking the wrong question, because you’re preoccupied with the idea that `char[]` was the best way to process a string. Your method name is even a double-misnomer, as you’re neither processing a string nor reversing it. Consider `int[] a = IntStream.range(0, s.length) .map(index -> s[index]) .map(Character::toUpperCase) .toArray(); String str = new String(a, 0, a.length);` or if you’re using a string as starting point, `int[] a = sourceString.codePoints().map(Character::toUpperCase).toArray();` but, of course, `String str = sourceString.toUpperCase();` is even simpler.

Comment: See also [How can I reverse one single string in Java 8 using Lambda and Streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47504758/2711488) and [Simplest way to print an `IntStream` as a `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20266422/2711488) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static public void reverseString(char[] s) {
    Character[] upperCaseArray = IntStream.range(0, s.length)
            .mapToObj(index -> s[index])
            .map(Character::toUpperCase)
            .toArray(Character[]::new);
}
```

Comment: `char[]` is not the same as `Character[]`