# How to reverse a String with java-stream

Tags: java, java-stream

```
public String reverseStream(String str){
    String reversedStr = IntStream.iterate(str.length(), c -> c > 0, c -> c-1)
               .forEach(c ->str.charAt(c))
               .collect(joining());
    return reversedStr;
```

My aim is to reverse an input String with java-stream by iterating it backwards.
I don´t know why this is not working. Perhaps the conversion of the stream to a String is wrong but I don't know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();`?

Comment: Here are some solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504758/how-can-i-reverse-one-single-string-in-java-8-using-lambda-and-streams

Comment: `forEach` is terminal operation. It doesn't produce stream, in fact its return type is `void`. You want to *map* index to *String* representing character at that position. So something like `.mapToObj(c -> ""+str.charAt(c))` is what you want. BTW you need to fix your starting index (remember that they start with 0 so if string has length N then its last index is ...?).

Comment: Anyway you **shouldn't be reversing string character after character** because in Unicode there are characters which are created by combining two characters (look up "surrogate pairs"). So when at start some symbol was created via `char1char2` after reversion you would end up with `char2char1` which will no longer represent that symbol. Use StringBuilder#reverse method instead since it handles such cases for us.